# Pandas: Fill in missing indexes with specific ordered values that are already in column.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have extracted a one-column dataframe with specific values. Now this is what the dataframe looks like:

```
           Commodity  
0              Cocoa
4             Coffee
6              Maize
7               Rice
10             Sugar
12             Wheat
```

Now I want to respectively fill each index that has no value with the value above it in the column so It should look something like this:

```
            Commodity  
0               Cocoa
1               Cocoa
2               Cocoa
3               Cocoa
4              Coffee
5              Coffee
6               Maize
7                Rice
8                Rice
9                Rice
10              Sugar
11              Sugar
12              Wheat
```

I don't seem to get anything from the pandas documentation Working with Text Data. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `df.reindex(range(13).bfill()`?

Comment: @Mathias711 almost... it should be `ffill`

Comment: @piRSquared always mix those up. Trial and error :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I think it's working better with 'ffill'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I create a new index with `pd.RangeIndex`.  It works like `range` so I need to pass it a number one greater than the max number in the current index.

```
df.reindex(pd.RangeIndex(df.index.max() + 1)).ffill()

   Commodity
0      Cocoa
1      Cocoa
2      Cocoa
3      Cocoa
4     Coffee
5     Coffee
6      Maize
7       Rice
8       Rice
9       Rice
10     Sugar
11     Sugar
12     Wheat
```

Answer (score 1):

First expand the index to include all numbers

```
s = pd.Series(['Cocoa', 'Coffee', 'Maize', 'Rice', 'Sugar', 'Wheat',], index=[0,4,6,7,10, 12], name='Commodity')
s = s.reindex(range(s.index.max() + 1))
```

Then do a `backfill`

```
s.bfill()
```